# Will a VirtualBox VM created on a Windows host run on a Mac host?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

If I create a VM in Virtual Box on a Windows host, including installing a guest OS, will that VM run on a Mac OSX host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. I am constantly using virtual machines created on Windows on a Mac too and viceversa and I have never had any compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and it's the same between GNU/Linux and Windows. I never experience any problems.